# Not able to install tree comand in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, vmware-player

My ubuntu is running on windows 7 using VMWARE player. I was try to install tree command . but it failed. could you help me why?

I am using "sudo app-get install tree" command and it is failing with

```
E: unable to locate package tree
```

Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-24 generic x86_64)

Regards,
Koushik

Comment: @Tim there IS a package called tree in the official repo: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tree

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package `tree` is available in [Universe](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/universe/base/tree). Check that you have it enabled:

[image]

Then just do the usual

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tree
```

---

All Ubuntu repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse) can be enabled by following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

Comment: Not able to install in Ubuntu 15.10, although universe is enabled.

Comment: @Rexford http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/tree

Comment: but I have`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main restricted` in my sources.list ?

Comment: Well I can't see `universe` anywere in that line... Make sure universe is not commented and dont forget to run `sudo apt-get update`. Either way in that link you can download the file and install it using Software Center

Comment: Got to download it now from ppa in terminal now. Thanks